# How can I slow down the execution of a macro in MS-Access

Tags: performance, vba, ms-access

I have a macro in MS-Access that only runs correctly half the time on one computer, but when tested on another computer it runs 100% of the time.

I suspect that this is because the macro is running to fast, and not finishing the execution of one step before it moves to the next one.  Is there a way I can pause between steps?

The steps for my macro are as follows:

1. RunCode for Import-Data
2. Open Append Query
3. Open Append Query
4. Open Update Query
5. RunSQL for Delete-Data

The first step and the last step execute 100% of the time on both  computers, but the middle steps sometimes fail with no error. I have tried to add this code between the macro to slow it down. I can't figure out how to apply it correctly, or if this solution is even correct.

```
Public Function SlowMacro()
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated,  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seing your code would be helpful.  It doesn't make sense that it steps 2 through 4 fail without error.  What error handling do you have?  Ideally you want to find out why steps 2 through 4 are failing instead of using a workaround like a `Wait` routine.

Comment: `Application.Wait` will stop all of MS Access from executing anything, meaning you're gaining nothing. However, I think you're on the wrong track about what the problem is, but since you provided no details whatsoever I can't really suggest where to start looking for the actual problem.

Comment: There is no real code other than calling the function. The macro is just set to open append, and update queries.  Should I open them programmaticly instead?

Comment: With both Access 2003 and 2007, `Application.Wait` gives me a compile error, "Method or data member not found".  What is your Access version?  Can you confirm its `Application` object has a method named `Wait`?

Comment: I am using access 2007, and I get the same error.  I thought I was implementing the code wrong.  I pulled it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656(office.11).aspx its referenced as VBA for Excel.  I thought all VBA would work in all ms-Office programs.  I guess I was wrong in thinking so.  Is there any method I can use to slow down the macro?  I'm almost positive it is some kind of performance issue.

Comment: The macro also runs fine when I turn on action confirmations, but its not practical for me to ask the user to select "yes" 5x per time they run the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your `SlowMacro()` function to cause a 2 second pause, you can use code from the Access Web: [API: Make code go to Sleep](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0021.htm)

Then I think this should work as your function.

```
Public Function SlowMacro()
    sSleep 2000
End Function
```

These are the key pieces from that web page I linked.

```
Private Declare Sub sapiSleep Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "Sleep" _
        (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub sSleep(lngMilliSec As Long)
    If lngMilliSec > 0 Then
        Call sapiSleep(lngMilliSec)
    End If
End Sub
```